# How can I create a square AlertDialog?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make an `AlertDialog` square? I've tried writing code like the one below, but I can't seem to make it square for some reason.
I tried experimenting by changing width to margin, but I couldn't make it square. Also, with AspectRatio, I can make it square, but I can't specify the size.

If anyone knows a method to make an `AlertDialog` square while specifying its size, please let me know.

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=77ca120634d8ec22500bbd6ef4d61166)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:  AlertDialog(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      content: Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is already squared alert can you add your expected design?

Comment: No, it's not a square. Have you confirmed it in DartPad?

Comment: You don't need Rounded border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **AlertDialog** take the total allocated width of the parent.

One of the way to solve that, will be to put your alert dialog in a **SizedBox** where you will specify the width.

```
Center(
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: AlertDialog(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        content: Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no other way other than wrapping it in a `SizedBox` widget or `Container` widget and specify `height` & `width`

```
SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  child: AlertDialog(
    shape:
        const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    content: Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, that still doesn't allow me to create a square AlertDialog.

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention, I edited my answer you can check it.